# How to cancel associated Runnables when CountDownLatch.await() is interrupted

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm using a `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` object (`latch`) to control a set of `Runnable`s which get executed via a thread pool (which could also be executing other `Runnable`s).

In certain (and desirable) instances, the main thread is interrupted whilst waiting in `latch.await()`. and I need to catch and deal with `java.lang.InterruptedException`.

What I want to do is to interrupt all the threads that are currently running in the thread pool on behalf of this particular latch, and cancel any `Runnable`s that are queued to run in that pool. To re-iterate: I can't simply interrupt everything in the pool and cancel all pending queued `Runnable`s as it used by other processes.

I presume this is a standard construct, but can't find it.

Therefore before I embark on implementing this from scratch, I would be delighted to know if Java has a canned object or a standard approach for doing this.

Comment: I would suggest that you should use another pool for the threads that you want to cancel so that you can call `shutdownNow()` on it.

Comment: Obviously all of your threads can watch a `volatile boolean shutdown` field and stop when it goes to true.

Comment: @Gray, your second idea has some potential; if I can find something I can override in java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService which is called when a Runnable is about to be ran. Then I can check the shutdown flag and not run that task.

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer and expanded it

Comment: Awesome. Am looking now. +1 as already it is useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't simply interrupt everything in the pool and cancel all pending queued Runnables as it used by other processes

The easiest fix to this is to separate out these `Runnable`s into their own thread-pool so you can then call `shutdownNow()` on that pool only which interrupts all of the tasks in that pool.  Sounds like you can't do that.

An alternative would be to teach your code to look for a `volatile boolean shutdown` field and stop running once that field goes to `true`.

```
 static final volatile boolean shutdown;
 ...
 public void run() {
      if (shutdown) {
         return;
      }
      ...
 }
```

Or if your tasks loop then you'd do:

```
 public void run() {
      while (!shutdown && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
         ...
      }
 }
```

If you don't have control over your `Runnable` class then you could write a little wrapping class that looks at the `shutdown` boolean:

```
 public class WrappedRunnable implements Runnable {
      private final Runnable delegate;
      public WrappedRunnable(Runnable delegate) {
          this.delegate = delegate;
      }
      public void run() {
          if (!shutdown) {
             delegate.run();
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: From Bathsheba: I can't do another pool due to adjacent and an indeterminate number of tasks using the same pool.

Comment: Don't stick inline comments @Bathsheba.  Stick them here.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, inspired from @Gray, was to extend `CountDownLatch` to include a field `private volatile boolean m_interrupted = false;`

Then in `@Override public void CountDownLatch.await()` I set this flag to `true` if I catch an `java.lang.InterruptedException` object.

The neat thing about this is that I am already passing `latch` into all the `Runnable`s in order to call `latch.countDown()` in a finally block.

So in the class that I've extended from `Runnable`, I check the interrupted status before doing any further work.

(Stopping any running threads is done using `interrupt()`).